# Select file to get name and path but save under a different name Access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am exporting data from Access to Excel. In the code below, a query is run in Access and exports the results to a template file in Excel. I want to save the file as a name different from the template.

- Template name = Server Data Collection Form Template.xlsx
- File name = Server Data Collection Form + Department name from form drop-down.

I am having trouble saving the file under a different name and in the same directory as the template file.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
On Error GoTo SubError

'Open file dialog to get filename and path so you don't hard code it

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim fn As String
    Dim fc As Integer
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fd.Title = "Select template file"
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.InitialFileName = "*Template.xlsx"
    fc = fd.Show
    fd.FilterIndex = 1

    If fc <> -1 Then
        MsgBox "No file opened"
        GoTo SubExit
    Else
        fn = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

' Get the depatment name to tack onto the file name
    Dim strDept As String
    strDept = Me.cboDept

'===The below code came from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yDmhzv7nns
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim qdfServerBill As QueryDef
    Dim rsServerBill As Recordset

'Set up reference to the query to export
    Set qdfServerBill = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_customer_input_file")

'Set up the parameter
    qdfServerBill.Parameters!prmBillMonth = Me.cboBillDate
    qdfServerBill.Parameters!prmDept = Me.cboDept

'Execute the query
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Set rsServerBill = qdfServerBill.OpenRecordset()

'Programmatically reference Excel and reference the workbook
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fn)

'Use paste from recordset to put in Excel sheet
    xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Customer Input").Cells(15, 2).CopyFromRecordset  rsServerBill

'Save Workbook, close, remove variables from memory
    xlWorkBook.Save
    xlWorkBook.Close

    Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set qdfServerBill = Nothing
    Set rsServerBill = Nothing

    MsgBox "Template is populated", vbOKOnly, "Process Successful"

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Sub

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & err.Number & "- " & err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An error occurred"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured this out.

Instead of:

```
'Save Workbook, close, remove variables from memory
xlWorkBook.Save
```

Do this:

```
'Save Workbook, close, remove variables from memory
xlWorkBook.SaveAs (Mid(fn, 1,66) & strDept), 51
```

The fn variable captures the full path and file name, and the Mid function captures the portion that I want to retain.

Comment: you can also just use replace:  xlWorkBook.SaveAs Replace(fn, "Template.xlsx", strDept & ".xlsx")

Comment: I like that solution better, @Sorceri. Thank you!